# "Такое" in "как такое могло случиться"

Tags: грамматика

In the phrase

> Как такое могло случиться в Соединенных Штатах?

, why is the adjective *такое* being used as a noun?

Comment: and why not?...

Comment: In this context,"такое" = 'such a thing'.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of [nominalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization).

It is what happens when a part of speech other than a noun starts to act as a noun in sentences.

In this particular case, *такое* is a collective adjective: a nominalized adjective which denotes a class or a group of things which share the property described by the adjective.

It is common both in Russian: *мне идёт чёрное; не путай тёплое с мягким; подобное лечится подобным* and in English: "Orange is the new black; eat fresh; think different".

In Russian, such adjectives are usually used in neuter singular.

Your phrase can be translated to English this way:

> How could such happen in the United States?

which almost perfectly parallels the Russian construct.

Answer (score 1):

"Как такое [происшествие] могло случиться в Соединённых Штатах?" The noun "событие" is dropped and should be inferred from the context. I this case "такое" is an adjective.

For example: "Какая машина нравится тебе? Мне - красная. А мне - синяя."

Answer (score 0):

"Takoe" can be both an adjective and a pronoun. Here we have a pronoun "this" used as a subject. I.e. How could all this have happened in the USA?

Comment: Thanks, могло is the past form of can but in russian, it can be 'could' and could have? like "it could be true' "she could have forgotten about it" as in "it is possibble thhat she forgot about the meeting?

Comment: what about "i could speak English when I was a child'" is the same past form used here too?

Comment: "She could have forgotten about it"-"Ona mogla (possibly) zabit..."

Comment: There's one form for all kinds of past tenses existing in English, i.e. it will be always могло, могла, мог  with a simple infinitive and a perfect as well.

Comment: "I could speak English"-"Ya mog razgovarivat na Angliiskom"

Comment: What do ya mean? You mean the past form of can in russian can supplant all the usages of the subunctive mood?

Comment: If you mean: "She could have forgotten about it if she hadn't been so clever", you'd better say: "Ona mogla bi zabit...".

Comment: The difference in using "could" and "could have+V-ed" is that "could" can acquire the meaning of ability in the past and possibility (theoretical or factual in the present/future) but "could have+V-ed" deals with possibility in the past (indicative) or contingent possibility (conditional).

Comment: To sound less dubious you may add Russian "i". She could forget about it"-she was able to forget (ona mogla zabit). "She could have forgotten about it"-it is possible she forgot about it (ona mogla i zabit).

Comment: I.e. "How could this have happened in the USA?" can be translated as: "I kak eto moglo sluchitsa v SShA?" or "Kak eto moglo (make here a very slight pause)    i sluchitsa v SShA?"

Answer (score 0):

It's translated as **"How that can happen?".** "такое=that"